# plt.contour in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a 2D contour plot given 3 numpy arrays of same size
X Y Z with (X,Y) the coordinates and Z the value at (X,Y).

Now, the function `plt.contour` seems to work only with a grid, and values at the intersection of the grid, and takes as input a rectangular grid only with 2D matrices as input.

see http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html

If the input for that function is (XX,YY,ZZ) then XX is a 2D rectangular array where every line is the same and every column is constant, while YY is a 2D rectangular array where every column is the same, and every line is constant.

Now, what function should I use, or what procedure should I follow, if I want to make the contour plot when the input values are NOT values taken on a grid?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `plt.tricontour`: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=tricontour#matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour

It draws contours on an unstructured triangular grid.

Little example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = x**2+np.sin(y)*y
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.tricontour(x,y,z)
ax.plot(x,y, 'r. ')
plt.show()
```

[image]